# Grunt jade compiler filling out empty attributes

Tags: gruntjs, npm, pug

I'm using the grunt-contrib-jade module to compile my Jade templates, if I leave my attribute blank like the following line:

```
article(ui-view)
```

It will compile to:

```
<article ui-view="ui-view"></article>
```

And that will break my AngularJS ui-router, as it will not handle the "ui-view" directive as if it is a named view (not what I want). Of course it's an option to write my jade file like this:

```
article(ui-view='')
```

But that's not what I want, is there some way to stop the jade compiler from filling out empty attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems good when there's `doctype html` at the beginning of the `.jade` file.

For partials that does not have `doctype`, it can also be solved by passing `{doctype: 'html'}` as option when calling Jade:

```
jade -O "{doctype:'html'}" partial.jade
```

It works for `grunt-contrib-jade` too by adding `doctype: 'html'` to the options, like so:

```
jade: {
  devel: {
    options: {
      pretty: true,
      doctype: 'html'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'src',
      src: [ '**/*.jade' ],
      dest: 'app',
      ext: '.html'
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean by just placing `{doctype:'html'}` on top of the file?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy No. Put `doctype html` on top of the file, or pass `{doctype:'html'}` to the jade compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use pure html in your jade: `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: The question is about how to handle empty attributes in Jade, falling back to HTML is an option (workaround). It do not answer how to do it **in** Jade.