# Angular controller is not instantiated after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

My original source code looks like this:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  /* @ngInject */
  function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('bar.foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        templateUrl: 'foo-view.html',
        controller: 'FooController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      });
  }

  /* @ngInject */
  function FooController() {
    window.alert('foo');
  }

  angular
    .module('my.foo', [])
    .config(config)
    .controller('FooController', FooController);

}(angular));
```

It works fine this way.

Then I minify it using ngAnnotate and UglifyJS, and get this code (formatted to easier reading):

```
function (a) {
  'use strict';
  function b(a) {
    a.state('bar.foo', {
      url: '/foo',
      templateUrl: 'foo-view.html',
      controller: 'FooController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
  }
  function c() {
    window.alert('foo')
  }
  b.$inject = ['$stateProvider'],
  a.module('my.foo', [])
   .config(b)
   .controller('FooController', c)
}(angular),
```

And, it does not work. When I go to the state `bar.foo` the controller do not get called. Others controllers and router states works fine. This one seems to get muted, the code inside the controller function is not called.

The console do not show any errors.

I do not know what to do or where to look at.

The entire JavaScript is bigger and is a concatenation of several small files. The single minified JS file has controllers before and after this one that works fine.

Debugging the minified file shows that the JavaScript is issuing the module definition calls to AngularJS, so the `module`, `config` and `controller` methods of Angular are called.

What should I search or check in the code? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any other file that defines (or potentially redefines) the "my.foo" module?

Comment: No, the module is not redefined and I have no files that "get" the module to further definitions.

Comment: Hmm... also, it's weird that the minification removed the parenthesis around your IIFE - this shouldn't work like this: `function(a){..}(p)`

Comment: All my files are enclosed into IIFEs, the concatenation+minification turns it all into a single file like: `!function(a){...}(angular),function(a){...}(angular),function(a){...}(angular);`, this is working so far (at least for the other routes and controllers).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I'm also compiling Jade templates into HTML. And my build settings for production environment is a little different than for development. Jade were outputting `<div ui-view="ui-view">` instead of an empty attribute, preventing the `ui-router` to load the template into the parent view, causing the controller to not being instantiated.

The minification of the JavaScript was not the problem. Sorry.

These questions helped me out:

- [ui-router nested route controller isn't being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866931/ui-router-nested-route-controller-isnt-being-called)
- [Grunt jade compiler filling out empty attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056224/grunt-jade-compiler-filling-out-empty-attributes)

Comment: I am not compiling any template but I still have this issue. I have gone through several suggestions on SO to no avail. Some of those options includes setting mangle to false in uglify task. I am out of options so far because code looks just fine even in minified version of my code.